# Float or String displayed within a JOptionPane window

Tags: java, string, joptionpane

I'm somewhat new to coding in Java but I have a quick question, I have a predefined float I'm trying to display in a JOptionPane window. Would it be easier to display the float or convert it to a string and then display that string, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

`JOptionPane.show....` gets an argument as message which is `Object`
and there is no diffrence between `Float` number or it's `String` ,
because they both are `Object`,

so there is no diffrence between this codes and all them do same thing

```
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "12.25");
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 12.25f);
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, String.valueOf(12.25f));
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, Float.toString(12.25f));
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "" + 12.25f);
```

but to create Messages working with Strings is easier than
Other data types and classes.

So i prefer `String` !

to convert `Float` number into `String`

- simply add `""` to it ex: `""+12.25f` but this way is uncommon .
- use one of this methods

  ```
  Float.toString(float_number);
  String.valueOf(float_number);
  ```